# Uploaded Image move to folder - php

Tags: php, image

I have tried some code to save my uploaded image in folder. The path of folder is `C:\xampp\htdocs\gripOffers\Store_Brand\store_admin\images`. I am unable to save it in folder. How to do this? Where am i doing wrong?

**Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $temp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $type = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $type;
    echo "<br>";

    if ((($type == "image/gif")
            || ($type == "jpeg")
            || ($type == "jpg")
            || ($type == "pjpeg")
            || ($type == "x-png")
            || ($type == "png"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 50000)
    ) {
        $m = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/Store_Brand/store_admin/images/" . $image);
        if ($m) {
            echo "uploaded!";
        } else {
            echo "no";
        }
    } else {
        echo "file type is not image";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to target path.

Comment: @u_mulder at which line?

Comment: @tabia, `move_uploaded_file` - that one. It wouldn't hurt to check the permissions on that directory as well.

Comment: @__FILE__ is a magic constant that gives you the filesystem path to the current .php file (the one that @__FILE__ is in, not the one it's included by if it's an include.

Comment: @savaliyanavneeet sorry but i didn't get what are you talking about

Comment: @tabia Try My Ans,, I hope its work ,

Comment: @tabia try to `Nidhi` ans..., its working

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is returned the root directory of project defined by the 'DocumentRoot' directive

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file" value="">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $temp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
    $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/"."gripOffers/Store_Brand/store_admin/images/".$image);
         echo "Your file upload successfully.";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
}
 ?>
```

Maybe it will help you

Comment: Your code echoes file uploaded successfully but when i check images folder there is no image.

Comment: your `images` folder have permission to read write data?check first

Comment: Yes it has permissions

Comment: @Nidhi Opps Its Not Working :P

Comment: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` print this and see what you get.. Check your project directory path.and make sure folder name has no space between two words.

Answer (score 0):

> Change The `<Form action="">` and Try This ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="example.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php

error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $temp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

     $file_extension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

     $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];

      $expensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");

      if(in_array($file_extension,$expensions)=== false){

         $message = "File Type Not allowed, Please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 500000){

         $message = '<h1> File size Too Large !! </h1>';
      }

      if(empty($message)==true){

         move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/gripOffers/Store_Brand/store_admin/images/".$image_name);

         $message = "<h1> Your file upload successfully. </h1>";
      }
      else{

         $message = "<h1> Something is Wrong  </h1>";
      }
}


if(isset($message))
{
echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$message.'</div>';
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Nothing happened!!